# Need help to resolve regular expression for Table of Contents

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse a document which contains Table Of Contents. The generated Document contains some text which is not part of table of content e.g. header and footer.

```
2.1 some_text 100
2.1. some_text 100
some_text 100
```

I have written one regex for validating whether the text is part of table of content.

```
(\d+(\.\d*)?)(.*)(\d{1,3})
```

But, it passed all the above text. I want it to failed in 3rd text i.e. some_text 100.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an anchor `^` in multiline mode (start of line):

```
(?m)^(\d+(\.\d*)?)(.*)(\d{1,3})
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQ3tI8/1)

You might even want to check if the number is at the end of the line with the `$` anchor:

```
(?m)^\d+(?:\.\d*)?.*\d{1,3}$
```

Note I removed all capturing groups from the last regex to keep it clean. If you plan to use the captured texts, you can revert them.